# How to debug sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, sidekiq

Today airbrake reported an exception. Its summary said that the problem occures when sidekiq tries retry the job after a failure. Here's what summary params look like:

```
{
 "retry"=>"true",
 "queue"=>"default",
 "class"=>"AdwordsReportWorker",
 "args"=>"[\"2\", \"2012-11-13\"]",
 "jid"=>"51d568e46c412adc327153c8",
 "error_message"=>"wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)",
 "error_class"=>"ArgumentError",
 "failed_at"=>"2012-11-14 13:56:12 UTC",
 "retry_count"=>"0",
 "controller"=>"",
 "action"=>""
}
```

I seems that the exception is only taking palce when the job fails and retries. I would like to debug this, but I can't get my head around where to start :-(

My questions are:

1. Under what conditions worker understands it **failed** finishing the job (from which he descides to retry)? How do I force the worker to fail in attempt to, say, reproduce the problem?
2. Is there a good tutorial on debugging/examples sidekiq workers?
3. I am using **sidekiq 2.3.3**. Will upgrading to newer version solve the problem?

**Bonus track**.
The [actual stacktrace](http://pastie.org/private/yccpaccwnc0mdzohkptl5a) unexpectedly ends up in

```
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:98:in `initialize'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find how do debug sidekiq, but apperently the problem I am referring to is a known bug in Rails.

Here are a few lines:

- https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/601
- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7770